# Set Latitude and Longitude Parameters using Google Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im starting to get into javascript, api and so on. Im trying to use the Google Maps api with some javascript, so my main idea was to create buttons with stored latitute and longitude values to display in the map, but im having a hard time passing the parameters over.

This is my code so far http://jsfiddle.net/dmorua1791/8bzkzoys/8/

```
<script>
    function load() {
        var mapOpt = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0,0.0),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOpt);
</script>
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the stored lat and lng over to function, how can I do that?

Comment: How are you "trying to pass the stored lat and lng over to function"?  What stored lat and lng?

Answer (score 1):

if you want your function will provide different places, then I think it will need a parameter `function load(lat,lng)` and then `center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),`

refer to : http://jsfiddle.net/8bzkzoys/9/

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do something like this:

```
function initialize() 
{
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851);
var geoLatLongCoordinates;
var lat = 37.422104808;
var lng = -122.0838851;
var zoom = 18;
var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
    if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) 
    {
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    }
    var myOptions = {zoom: zoom,center: myLatLng,mapTypeId: maptype};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```